# jQuery window resize and media query

Tags: javascript, jquery

Used jQuery lib:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

I have this jQuery code:

```
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
            var slider = $.fn.fsvs({
                speed               : 500,
                bodyID              : 'fsvs-body',
                selector            : '> .slide',
                mouseSwipeDisance   : 40,
                afterSlide          : function(){},
                beforeSlide         : function(){},
                endSlide            : function(){},
                mouseWheelEvents    : false,
                mouseWheelDelay     : false,
                mouseDragEvents     : false,
                touchEvents         : false,
                arrowKeyEvents      : false,
                pagination          : false,
                nthClasses          : false,
                detectHash          : false
            });
} else {
            var slider = $.fn.fsvs({
                speed               : 1000,
                bodyID              : 'fsvs-body',
                selector            : '> .slide',
                mouseSwipeDisance   : 40,
                afterSlide          : function(){},
                beforeSlide         : function(){},
                endSlide            : function(){},
                mouseWheelEvents    : true,
                mouseWheelDelay     : false,
                mouseDragEvents     : true,
                touchEvents         : true,
                arrowKeyEvents      : true,
                pagination          : true,
                nthClasses          : true,
                detectHash          : true
            });
}
        });
        </script>
```

I would like to add to this code a resize function to reload jquery upon window resize. I was able to find this code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // add the stuff here to execute the your slider again;
});
```

However, I have no idea how to use this code with my original code. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You copied all those values to change one? What is `$.fn.fsvs`? Weird way to call it, that is not the normal jQuery pattern.

Comment: I don't know much about jquery. I google and find what I need. I tried making some changes and the above code seemed to do what I need. I'm sure it's not the best way of doing things. Sorry.

Comment: Well unless that code has a destroy method, I am not sure if you can reload it.

Comment: The $.fn.fsvs comes from this code at this location. 

http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-CSS3-Based-Fullscreen-Vertical-Page-Slider-FSVS.html

Comment: Doesn't look to have a destroy method that I can tell, won't easily  be able to do what you are wanting then. (It is possible but I suspect the answer will be quite long)

Comment: Thanks for looking at it Turnerj. Appreciate it. :)

Comment: https://github.com/lukesnowden/FSVS/blob/master/js/fsvs.js#L630

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the problem by using the following code:

```
<script>
function refresh() { location.reload(); }
</script>
```

and

```
<body onresize="refresh()">
```

Not my best option but it works for a noob. 
Thank you all for taking the time and trying to help me.